# Is it scientifically backed that sensory signals always go through limbic/emotional brain system?

Tags: emotion, brain, emotional-intelligence

From the book [Emotional Intelligence 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974320625) by Travis Bradberry & Jean Greaves:

> The daily challenge of dealing effectively with emotions
> is critical to the human condition because our brains are
> hard- wired to give emotions the upper hand. Here’s how it
> works: everything you see, smell, hear, taste and touch travels through your body in the form of electric signals. These
> signals pass from cell to cell until they reach their ultimate
> destination, your brain. They enter your brain at the base
> near the spinal cord, but must travel to your frontal lobe
> (behind your forehead) before reaching the place where rational, logical thinking takes place. The trouble is, they pass
> through your limbic system along the way—the place where
> emotions are produced. This journey ensures you experience
> things emotionally before your reason can kick into gear.

[image]

Is the presented as fact that senses such as seeing/sight go through Emotional/Limbic system prior to reaching Rational neo-cortex layer. Is this the current scientific stance?

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that [emotional life is largely housed in the limbic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbic_system#Attentional_and_emotional_processes), the model seems to be over-simplistic to me. There are more complex emotions that are housed in the neocortex, not just the limbic system<sup>*</sup>. However, it can still be useful to teach for layman? Similarly to the [triune brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triune_brain) model.

For a good introductory video course on emotion, see [Human Emotion](https://www.youtube.com/), host by June Gruber, prof in Yale.

<sub>* I believe I have this claim when watching this course, but I cannot find the particular video that make that statement.</sub>